# MapIcon visibility issue Windows Phone 8.1 Bing Maps

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, bing-maps

In WP8.1 project I created MapIcon and added it in MapElements. In some levels of zoom image is drawen but sometimes when I zoom in or zoom out it disappears (I thin when place names are to close to image). How is this possible to fix? Thanks in advance!

Code behind

```
        mapIcon = new MapIcon();
        mapIcon.NormalizedAnchorPoint = new Point(0.5, 1.0);
        mapIcon.Image = RandomAccessStreamReference.CreateFromUri(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/mapIcon.png"));
        mapIcon.Title = "You are here!";
        MyMapControl.MapElements.Add(mapIcon);
        mapIcon.Location = new Geopoint(new BasicGeoposition()
        {
            Latitude = geoLoc.Latitude,
            Longitude = geoLoc.Longitude
        });
```

XAML

```
        <Grid Grid.Row="0" x:Name="ContentRoot" Margin="0,0,0,0">
        <Maps:MapControl
            x:Name="MyMapControl"
            MapServiceToken="<my token>"
            ZoomLevel="13.5"
            LandmarksVisible="True"
            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
            VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
            Margin="0,0,0,0"
            >
        </Maps:MapControl>
    </Grid>
```

Answer (score 2):

MapIcon elements are not guaranteed to be shown, they may be obscured by other elements, or if they are too close.

If you want to have a control that always shows, then use a XAML element: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn792121.aspx#showing_xaml_controls_and_shapes_on_the_map

Comment: Thanks for help. I added Image element in XAML as is described in above link and my icon is now always visible on map. But when i manipulate with map the icon is very shaky. It is not like MapiIcon, that is always in exact location. Do you have any tip for that?

Comment: Perfect Thanks loads:)

Comment: @ArminPlohl have you found out any Tip or solution to the problem you've mentioned in the above comment..?  "when i manipulate with map the icon is very shaky. It is not like MapiIcon, that is always in exact location. Do you have any tip for that?"

Comment: @Jogy  Adding XAML elements like Image, on Map makes map control very laggy... instead using MapIcon it works smooth but with visibility issue in certain zoom level.  So is there any solution to show mapIcon in every zoom level..?